# How to send direct message using MGTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I want to send direct message to my Twitter followers using **https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages/new.format** but not getting how to do this. does any one can provide me any sample code for this ?

I have search a lot for this but not getting How I will get these values :

oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_token.

Thank in Advance

Comment: Finally I got the answer it's done.                                             -(NSString *)sendDirectMessage:(NSString *)message to:(NSString *)username

Comment: Can you put code for send Direct Message??

Comment: @Leena if you get any issues fell free to post queries.

Comment: Sir query is regarding MGTwitterEngine.  Using this SDK i can post tweet but can not fetch tweets.

Comment: @VinodJat I am also using `MGTwitterEngine`. Can you please elaborate with `code ` how to send direct message to a follower on twitter?

Comment: @iDev simply use the above method to send direct message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to send Direct message using Twitter Engine

```
  appDelegate._engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
        appDelegate._engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
        appDelegate._engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;
```

once you get authenticated this method get called

```
  #pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterControllerDelegate

    - (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *)username {
     NSLog(@"Authenicated for %@", username);
     [appDelegate._engine sendDirectMessage:@"Test for Twitter direct message" to:username];
}
```